# Waiting for Ionic connectivity with ionic-app-scripts issue

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, visual-studio-code

> Hi, Waiting for connectivity with ionic-app-scripts continues with
>   ionic serve--lab?

```
[app-scripts] [18:17:21]  tslint: ...orkSpace_Ionic3_MobileApp/prototype/src/pages/profile-details/profile-details.ts, line: 2
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-app-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-app-scripts...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ionic-app-scripts...
```

> **Ionic Info :**

Ionic:

```
   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.0.3 (C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.11

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : browser 5.0.3

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
   NodeJS            : v9.1.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 5.5.1
   OS                : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\user2\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

> Below I have updated mine package.json file.
>   **package.json**

```
{
      "name": "name",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "author": "Ionic Framework",
      "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
        "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release",
        "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
        "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
        "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
      },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try **`npm run start`** instead of **`ionic serve`**.
This will work.

Comment: `npm run start` will depend on the `package.json` script, it's totally unclear and not a solution

Answer (score 3):

Check whether you have installed any Antivirus for protection

If yes turn off **Browser protection** and do `ionic serve --host 0.0.0.0`

You can turn it on after a successful ***serve***.

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)

Answer (score 2):

Try the modified part. And try executing "npm start" command

```
 {
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --aot --minifyjs --minifycss --release",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve"  //instead of ionic:serve, write start
  },
```

Comment: After type command ionic start , it showing  "  You are already in an Ionic project directory. Do you really want to start another project here? (y/N) " so I don't want to start another new project just I need to run existing project with bug free.Thanks

Comment: Try npm start not ionic start

Comment: Awesome , but I would like to  see result as ionic serve --lab run command .

Comment: Do one thing.. manually write ionic-lab on the browser... localhost:8100/ionic-lab

Comment: I would like to test above result on Devapp (IOS)  "unable to load Page " the request timed out !!!!  which command to run ? because ionic serve -c can't working .

Answer (score 2):

The reason is in that the app starts with 0.0.0.0 IP address.
Try to add in our command "--address localhost" part.
So

```
ionic serve --address localhost
```

Answer (score 2):

If none of these works,
then make sure your **FIREWALL is OFF**. (into antivirus software as well.)

Answer (score 0):

Do not downgrade the node version, update the version of "app-scripts":

To get the latest @ionic/app-scripts, please run:

> npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

I got this error only when I was connected to VPN. Once I turned VPN off, It start working again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ionic 6 and you came here looking for a solution to the following problem (like me):

```
Waiting for connectivity with ng...
```

Then check this answer, it's probably the solution to all your problems (remember to upvote if it helped you):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74412994/6499181

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue after upgrading node js. This command helped me :

```
ionic serve --external
```