# ionic serve "connectivity with ng" problem

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

I don't know what I updated or what I did but when I run the ionic serve command it keeps saying "[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...".

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.16.3 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.6.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 2.4.5
   @capacitor/android : 2.4.8
   @capacitor/core    : 2.4.5
   @capacitor/ios     : 2.4.8

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed globally
   native-run  : not installed globally

System:

   NodeJS : v14.17.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 6.14.14
   OS     : macOS Big Sur
```

Comment: Please share your `package.json`

Comment: here is package.json https://justpaste.it/8zmct

Comment: Please have a look to this solution, it may resolve your issue https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/waiting-for-connectivity-with-ionic-app-scripts-continues-after-upgraded-to-v4/137391/6

Comment: or also try this `npm run start` instead of `ionic serve`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried the steps in the link you shared before. I did extensive research and followed all the logical steps, but it didn't solve my problem. I just restarted mac and it is currently serving. This is the first time I've encountered such a problem and it's really weird. Maybe someone in the future can try to restart their computer if they encounter such a problem. 

Comment: hahaha! Good Luck :) :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem using Ionic 6.

Running either of the following two commands resulted in the error "Waiting for connectivity with ng...":

```
ionic serve
ionic cordova run android --l
```

I think this issue occurs due to some network misconfiguration, however none of the above answers worked for me. Rebooting the mac didn't work either.

The only workaround I found was to add the --external option to the commands, that way everything works like a charm again.

For example:

```
ionic cordova run android --l --external
```

If it helps someone, remember to upvote this answer. Thanks and enjoy.